# keras custom loss function Value error on convert to tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to implement a custom loss function for keras using tensorflow backend. The idea i'm working with is to provide the "Cost" of a "Signal" as the y_true and handle the signals as the y_pred. This is basically a complicated classification situation.

As an example lets say I have 3 possible output signals and N samples then I would have a cost matrix that is Nx3 and my predictions would also be Nx3 (So as to not run into problems with y_true and y_pred needing to be the same size.

The way I am selecting my actual signal is by taking the max of the three output values and then the cost for this signal is the value in the cost matrix at the corresponding index. Total cost is the sum of these individual costs.

I have implemented this in tensorflow (I needed to use gather_nd so I couldn't use keras.backend but all the examples I have read online don't seem to care about this fact). The code for my implementation is:

```
def maxSignalLossTF(costs, signals):

    signalChoices = tf.transpose(tf.stack((tf.to_int64(tf.range(tf.shape(signals)[0])), tf.argmax(signals, axis=1))))

    signalCosts = tf.gather_nd(costs, signalChoices)
    return tf.reduce_sum(signalCosts)
```

I have confirmed this function to be working as expected by comparing it to the numpy equivalent. I am passing this loss function to my model when compiling:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(250, input_shape=(trainX.shape[1],)))
model.add(Activation('relu'))
model.add(Dropout(0.1))

model.add(Dense(250))
model.add(Activation('relu'))

model.add(Dense(3))
model.add(Activation('linear'))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss=maxSignalLossTF)
```

All of this seems to work fine until I try to fit the model with:
    model.fit(TrainX, TrainY, epochs=100)
At which point the console spits out the following unhelpful message

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tensortest.py", line 331, in <module>
    model.fit(TrainX, TrainY, epochs=100)
  File "/home/myname/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/models.py", line 845, in fit
    initial_epoch=initial_epoch)
  File "/home/myname/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1457, in fit
    self._make_train_function()
  File "/home/myname/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py", line 1001, in _make_train_function
    self.total_loss)
  File "/home/myname/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/keras/optimizers.py", line 398, in get_updates
    m_t = (self.beta_1 * m) + (1. - self.beta_1) * g
  File "/home/myname/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/ops/math_ops.py", line 856, in binary_op_wrapper
    y = ops.convert_to_tensor(y, dtype=x.dtype.base_dtype, name="y")
  File "/home/myname/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 611, in convert_to_tensor
    as_ref=False)
  File "/home/myname/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/ops.py", line 676, in internal_convert_to_tensor
    ret = conversion_func(value, dtype=dtype, name=name, as_ref=as_ref)
  File "/home/myname/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 121, in _constant_tensor_conversion_function
    return constant(v, dtype=dtype, name=name)
  File "/home/myname/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/constant_op.py", line 102, in constant
    tensor_util.make_tensor_proto(value, dtype=dtype, shape=shape, verify_shape=verify_shape))
  File "/home/myname/anaconda2/lib/python2.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_util.py", line 364, in make_tensor_proto
    raise ValueError("None values not supported.")
ValueError: None values not supported.
```

I tried to track down where this message was coming from in keras and tensorflow but while I found the functions it did not yield much insight for me as to what I am doing wrong. I have out of desperation also completely implemented to calculation manually using `tf.convert_to_tensor()` on my input X and Y which had no issues so I'm pretty stumped at this point what is going wrong.

I'm new to Keras and tensorflow and while I have looked at basically every example I could find its very likely I am missing something pretty simple. So any help is greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance

Also if there are pre-made solutions to this type of cost set up I would be happy to know about them. I came up with this idea after tinkering with a few different standard options without much success so I decided to try something that would give me more direct control over incentivizing the various output signals which better capture the underlying problem (Mis classification of some samples is not as important as misclassifying other samples)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is happening because your loss function is not differentiable regarding your model's weights.

Your result is totally based on "constants" coming from "y_true" (which is "costs").

Although it's true you can change the result of the loss function by changing which signals are the greatest, it's impossible to know which direction to take without having differentiable functions.

---

At first, I can't think of a replacement to your function, and from what I understood of it, all that matters is that one of the 3 results be greater than the others, independently of what their values are. Is that really your intention?

Ex:

```
For a cost [1,4,2], any of the following signals are ok by your function:

[10,9,3]
[1,0,0]   
[10e+45,1,10e-12]
etc....

as long as the first one is greater, your loss is the lowest.
```

Comment: Thanks, you are right, the intent of this function was that it only cared about the cost associated with the particular signal that was emitted. I was approaching the problem from an evolutionary computation sort of mindset where I wanted to weight the cost of producing various signals to more closely reflect the actual cost of the actions associated with those signals. I also made a second loss function of the mean product of costs and signals. `tf.reduce_sum((S/tf.reduce_sum(S, axis=1, keep_dims=True))*costs)` this one "worked" but didn't do anything. maybe ML is the wrong tool for this?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your goal... is it a model to decide "which action to take" (being each of the 3 elements in a sample one of the possible actions)?

Comment: Yes exactly. Do you have any suggestions for how to structure such a problem such that it can take into account that the various actions do not always have the consequences? Or am I looking at the problem in a counter-intuitive manner?

Comment: Just make `y_true` be a vector with the desired action as a one-hot vector. Action1 = [1,0,0], Action2 = [0,1,0], Action3 = [0,0,1], and use any regular loss, such as `categorical_crossentropy`.

Comment: Is there a special reason not to do this?

Comment: The reasoning in my mind was that I am working with time series data and taking the wrong action at certain times is worst than at others. By doing the weighting I was trying to capture this information and incentivize the model to take a cautious position if it didn't have a strong conviction to the signal. 

I have also been doing some testing with some standard classifier tools with sklearn using essentially your suggestion for converting to labels and have had better success than with this custom function so I'm starting to think I might have over-thought the problem.

Comment: You might want to use the weights later, but what people usually do is simply multiply the loss values by the weights. Some moves get more important than others, but all keep differentiable.

Comment: Thanks! I really appreciated your input. I did eventually try the multiplying the weights approach and it worked (as in was differentiable as expected) But I have still not achieved the quality of results I am aiming for. I'm not taking a proper course in the topic to get a better grasp of some of these basics my informal tinkering has missed. But thanks again for your time reply to me :)